# How can I get tax rates for all countries?

Tags: import, tax

I have set up tax rates for 60 countries but I want to have every country covered. I tried this in the CSV file

```
"* 19%","*","*","*","19.0000","","","","MwSt.",""
```

but Magento doesn't accept a * for all countries. Is there a list for all countries where I can just copy from?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get a list of all country codes is by directly accessing / exporting the data in the 'directory_country' database table if you have access.  This lists all countries with both their ISO 2 and ISO 3 codes.

Note: the above is valid for both Magento 1.x and 2.x and as you have not specified I don't want to presume.

I've also created a gist with the output from the table if it helps: https://gist.github.com/johnhughes1984/e749cee0e3713d49dd90ebe9b305858b